# Using oauth-4-laravel for Facebook login, what is $code referring to?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, laravel-4

Im pretty new with the facebook sdk thing... and i want to make a facebook login on a website using oauth-4-laravel, but i can't figure out what the $code mean.

```
    // get data from input
$code = Input::get( 'code' );

// get fb service
$fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook' );

// check if code is valid

// if code is provided get user data and sign in
if ( !empty( $code ) ) { etc...
```

Where can i get the Input::get('code') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `code` parameter is set by the Facebook login page, basically it works like this :

- your app generates a Facebook login URL and redirects the user to it
- the user enters his credentials and gives permission to your app
- Facebook redirects the user back to your app with the "code" parameter set

I suggest you read the [documentation](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) of the package you're using, it includes a nice example.